# Rails active_model_serializer conditional include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers, ruby-on-rails-5

When I have a has_many/belongs_to relationship in Rails 5 API with `active_model_serializers` I can pass the option to include a nested model.

```
def show
    render json: @post, include: ['comments']
end
```

It's also possible to get multiple layers of nesting.

```
def show
    render json: @post, include: ['comments', 'comments.comment_likes']
end
```

I can't find documentation anywhere about adding conditions to the include statement. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
def show
    render json: @post, include: ['comments'] { top_contributor: true } 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In master (which will soon become RC4), a PR has been merged that allows for the following at serializer level:

```
belongs_to :user, if: :include_user?
def include_user?
  current_user.admin?
end
```